# c++ file search database file and cout next line

Tags: c++, database, text-files

I have 2 codes here, the first one here prompts you for a number, then tells you what is on that line number in the text file "example.txt"

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s;
    vector <string> v;
    ifstream fileInput;
    int qwe = 0;
    fileInput.open("example.txt");
    while (getline( fileInput, s ))
    {
        v.push_back( s );
    }
    cout << "number: " << endl;
    cin >> qwe;
    cout << "line " << qwe << ": " << v[ qwe ] << endl;
    fileInput.close();
}
```

and a second code here prompts the user for input then adds a "?" at the beginning because it's for my algorithm in the future, it will be used then. But then it searches for that in the text file and gives the user the line number of what the user inputted

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream fileInput;
    int offset;
    string line;
    string search;

    cout << "Hi" << endl;
    getline(cin, search);
    search = "?" + search;
// open file to search
    fileInput.open("example.txt");
    if(fileInput.is_open())
    {
        while(getline(fileInput, line))
        {
            for(unsigned int curLine = 2; getline(fileInput, line); curLine++)
            {
                if (line.find(search) != string::npos)
                {

                    cout << "found: " << search << " line: " << curLine << endl;
                }
            }
        }
        fileInput.close();
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file.";
}
```

So my problem is that I need to sort of combine these codes, I need it so that it prompts the user for input and then it figures out the line number, and then it couts the next line, how do I do this?

Comment: Ok... you don't appear to be asking a question...? EDIT: ignore my flag, he added a question after I flagged it for not asking a question. :p

Comment: Yeah sorry about that I accidentlly hit submit before putting the question haha

Comment: It's a good idea to indent your code in the conventional way so that others can read it.

Comment: A lot of times when I post questions on here most of you just critique my questions, would you mind actually answering them instead?

Comment: Give us some time.. I was formatting the code so they can actually read it.. It was extremely hard to read the way it was posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this would do:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string input;

    std::cout<<"Enter a line to search for: \n";
    std::getline(std::cin, input);

    std::fstream File("example.txt", std::ios::in);

    if (File.is_open())
    {
        std::string line;
        int line_count = 0;

        while(std::getline(File, line))
        {
            if (line.find(input) != std::string::npos)
            {
                std::cout<<"The line found was: \""<<line<<"\" at line: "<<line_count<<"\n";

                if (std::getline(File, line))
                {
                    std::cout<<"The line after that is: \""<<line<<"\"\n";
                    ++line_count;
                }
                else
                {
                    std::cout<<"There are no lines after that!\n";
                }
            }
            ++line_count;
        }

        File.close();
    }
}
```

With an example file of:

```
hello world
I am testing
finding lines
```

you can search for "hello" and it will return line 0 aka the first line..

However, if you turn on `find_approximate_line` and searched for "hey world", it will still return line 0 because of the `HammingDistance` algorithm.

If you don't care about partial/close matches then you can remove the HammingDistance algorithm and keep using the `std::string.find`.

One example output is:

```
Enter a line to search for:
> hello world

The line found was: "hello world" at line: 0
The line after that is: "I am testing"
```

Comment: error log says "[Error] 'uint_32t' in namespace std does not name a type

Comment: I changed it to `unsigned int`.

Comment: and this doesn't answer my question, the question was how do I combine my 2 codes so that if you type something it couts the next line in the file

Comment: So instead of printing the line found, you want to print the line after the one found?

Comment: Yeah if that's possible then that's exactly what I need

Comment: Fixed. All you had to do was add an extra `std::getline` in an if-statement.